# JSON validation failed for IncludeScopes in appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Why am I getting `Expression must be of type object` for `IncludeScopes` in my `appsettings.json` file?

[image]

Here's a simplified version of the JSON needed to show the warning.
To reproduce this, you just need to create a blank ASP.NET Core project and update appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "serilog": {
    "write-to": {
      "sumologic.url": "http://localhost",
      "RollingFile.pathFormat": "R\\Document\\API\\Logs-{Date}.log"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @David Klempfner, please share enough code to reproduce your issue. Also please share the json instead of screenshot.

Comment: Hi @David Klempfner, I got it. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [the github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/835#issuecomment-389567342) said, you add the `IncludeScopes` to the wrong level. Change like below:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      },
      "IncludeScopes": false
    },
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
    
  },
  "serilog": {
    "write-to": {
      "sumologic.url": "http://localhost",
      "RollingFile.pathFormat": "R\\Document\\API\\Logs-{Date}.log"
    }
  }
}
```